# alter ssh message for VerifyHostKeyDNS / SSHFP

Tags: domain-name-system, ssh

For many of our **openssh** servers we have their **fingerprints** in DNS (**SSHFP**). We do not yet use secure DNS, i.e. though the FP is in DNS, a connect like

```
    ssh -o VerifyHostKeyDNS=yes <user>@sshserver
```

will be answered like

```
    Matching host key fingerprint found in DNS.
```

and unfortunately, but in full accordance with man *man ssh*

```
    Host key verification failed.
```

Since we have many external clients who come across this message it often invokes confusion and questions. Is there a way to change these messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messages are [hardcoded into the SSH client](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Host%20key%20verification%20failed&type=). So unfortunately without changing the messages in the source code, recompiling the binaries for all possible platforms and distributing those files to your clients, who then have to replace the official binaries with your modified version there is no way to do this.

Extract from sshconnect2.c:

```c
verify_host_key_callback(struct sshkey *hostkey, struct ssh *ssh)
{
    if (verify_host_key(xxx_host, xxx_hostaddr, hostkey) == -1)
        fatal("Host key verification failed.");
    return 0;
}
```